# how to list the specific user acces type for the database in db2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

The user 'XX' present under group 'YY'. I want to find the access type of the user 'xx' for a database. Which query can I use?

I am using a Linux environment with Db2 v10.5

Comment: What is "access type"?

Comment: type of privilege having to the user to access the database.

Comment: wouldn't you need connect privilege?

Comment: privileges like read or write or modify

Comment: yes I need connect privilege to check it

Comment: I tried with this below query but it returns zero records 
db2 "select * from SYSCAT.DBAUTH  where GRANTEE = 'XXX' "

Comment: I blogged about it a couple times and it links to key routines: http://blog.4loeser.net/2017/06/db2-security-privileged-insight.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query returns all privileges for the specified USERID:

```
SELECT distinct p.AUTHID, p.PRIVILEGE, p.OBJECTNAME, p.OBJECTSCHEMA, p.OBJECTTYPE
FROM SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES P, SYSIBMADM.AUTHORIZATIONIDS A,
TABLE (SYSPROC.AUTH_LIST_GROUPS_FOR_AUTHID('HLOESER')) as U 
WHERE p.privilege='CREATEIN' and a.authidtype='G' and a.authid=p.authid
AND (u.group=a.authid or a.authid='PUBLIC')
UNION
SELECT distinct p.AUTHID, p.PRIVILEGE, p.OBJECTNAME, p.OBJECTSCHEMA, p.OBJECTTYPE
FROM SYSIBMADM.PRIVILEGES P
WHERE p.authid='USERID'
```

The query is taken from this [blog post on using the Db2 administrative views and routines](http://blog.4loeser.net/2016/11/db2-security-implicit-privileges.html). If you leave out the WHERE clause, it should give you a table for all users.

Comment: Its Working.. Thanks a lot henrik.